# Iconified JFrame showing behind modal JDialog on win 7 taskbar click

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, jframe

I originally developed the following code on Win XP.  When you click the program icon in the XP taskbar, the parent frame remains iconified and the JDialog returns to focus, which is the behavior I want.  However, when clicking the program's taskbar icon on Win 7, the parent JFrame changes its state back to Normal and shows behind the app-modal JDialog.  I've tried overriding the JFrame's setExtendedState() method to intercept the frame's state change with no luck.

Is there a workaround for this, or is there a flaw my logic I need to address?

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestLogin extends JFrame {

public TestLogin() {
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    iconify(this);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("I'm a Frame!");
    this.setVisible(true);
    LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen(this);
}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    TestLogin frame = new TestLogin();  
}

public static void iconify(Frame frame) {
    int state = frame.getExtendedState();

    // Set the iconified bit
    state |= Frame.ICONIFIED;

    // Iconify the frame
    frame.setExtendedState(state);
}

public static void deiconify(Frame frame) {
    int state = frame.getExtendedState();

    // Clear the iconified bit
    state &= ~Frame.ICONIFIED;
    // Deiconify the frame
    frame.setExtendedState(state);
}


public class LoginScreen extends JDialog {

    private JFrame root;

    public LoginScreen(JFrame root) {
        super(root);
        this.root = root;
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("I'm a Dialog!");
        setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a bug in the java paradigm of "write once, run anywhere". If that is to include windows 7, then you might contact oracle and fill a bug report.

Regards,
Stéphane